# Error when installing: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, installation, rattle

Tried to install all rattle related packages by typing:

```
install.packages(rattle, dependencies = c("Depends","Suggests"))
```

and got this

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Hooman/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I already installed two individual packages in that folder and had no issue.

Comment: try `install.packages("rattle",dependencies=c("Depends","Suggests"))`

Answer (score 25):

@BenBolker posted an answer as a comment, perhaps because he is hoping that you will stare at the difference between your code and his and get a Zen-moment. He also thinks, being the modest gentleman that he is, that it's too simple to warrant any upvotes. So I am  feeling guilty that any upvotes are his rather than mine. I will now try to legitimately earn any upvotes.

The reason you got the error was the the `install.packages` function expects a character object, while you gave it the unquoted expression `rattle`. Ben uses a single element character vector `"rattle"`, thus conforming to the requirement of the function. Unlike some functions `install.packages` is not equipped to provide "non-standard evaluation" of its first argument.

R is a funny language at times with some inconsistent evaluation conventions. There are several functions where you can provide an unquoted expression and have it automatically converted to character. The list includes `library`, and its cousin, `require`, as well as `help`, `subset`, and `$`. These are considered "non-standard" evaluation by knowledgeable users, and they can have their pitfalls in programming. The error message tells you that R tried to convert what it "thought" would be a language object, a closure (which loosely is an R and LiSP term for function), to a character and did not succeed. You can see the same error with this console interaction:

```
> as.character(mean)
Error in as.character(mean) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

If you look at the `library` function mentioned by Ben and scroll down past the internal function definitions you eventually get to the mechanism whereby library avoids that error:

```
if (!character.only) 
            package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

This would also avoid the error, which I intentionally used as an example:

```
> as.character(substitute(mean))
[1] "mean"
```

The `substitute` function is doing processing on a language element taken to be a closure and the resulting object an R "name" has an `as.character` method.

Comment: To be fair, it's rather confusing (I think) because functions like `library()` and `require()` try to make life easier for the user (mistakenly, I think) by allowing them to specify either a character vector or a symbol

Comment: I hope I was not being unfair in any way. I remember having exactly the same confusion when starting R. I just regretted needing to "answer" a question when you provided the insight. Oh, I get it, you want me to remove my close vote. I can try. I didn't use my imperial close powers because I couldn't find a real duplicate, despite searching.

Comment: I didn't want you to do anything in particular, I was just commenting.

Comment: (Copied from an answer by OP): Yes it worked. install.packages("rattle",dependencies = c("Depends","Suggests")) "rattle" has to be enclosed by double quotes. I guess I have to send an email to Graham Williams @togaware.com to correct his instruction.

Comment: (Copied from an answer by OP:) One more question: if you cannot install packages from CRAN and internet and you need to copy the packages locally first and install them from the zip, although this works one package at a time, but it's rather a painful manual process as you don't know what package depends on what. Is there any way to instruct "install.packages" to install the package and its dependencies from local or set the repos locally and is there any way to download all the available(or dependant packages) at the same time?

Comment: I know you of all people know this Ben, but others may not know that they can find the list of dependencies in the target package's required DESCRIPTION file. I don't know for sure if the `dependencies = TRUE` setting of `install.packages` will then install all the dependencies if those source files have been placed in the current working directory, but I think that should work.