# Using "unit" as a variable in a facet_wrap plot with expand_limit returns "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use `unit` as a faceting variable, ggplot returns an error

```
library(ggplot2)
# Create and additional unit variable
cars$unit <- c(rep("mph",25),rep("smthingelse",25))
# Error
ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    expand_limits(y=0) +
    facet_wrap(~unit)
# Error in as.character(what) : 
#   cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

ggplot doesn't return an error when the variable has a different name, for example `unit2`:

```
cars$unit2 <- cars$unit
ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    expand_limits(y=0) +
    facet_wrap(~unit2)
```

It shares the same error message with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23846918/cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-character), but I don't think it is related. I tried but I did not manage to use `facet_wrap(~substitute(unit))`.

Comment: Your example runs for me with no error. `unit` is a fairly vital function in the **grid** package, upon which **ggplot2** is built. You might have an older version of **ggplot2** that has a now fixed bug that caused a name collision in some cases.

Comment: I don't get the error, it works with both unit and unit2.

Comment: Thanks I updated ggplot2 to a more recent version `install.packages("ggplot2")` fixed it.

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked the `grid` package and was surprised to see that [it was removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grid/index.html). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349398/r-package-grid-disappeared) explains that `grid` has become a base package [in version 1.8.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/doc/changes.txt).

Answer (score 0):

This was due to an old version of ggplot2

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

Fixed my issue.